# Spring Boot Builder with abstract classes

Tags: java, abstract-class, lombok, builder

I have a class called Property which is an abstract class and has the following properties:

```
@SuperBuilder
@Setter
@Getter
public abstract class Property {

    private String id;

    private String address; //TODO -> Create Value Object

    private String description;

    private Float squareFootage;

    private Integer bedrooms;

    private Year yearBuilt;

    private Integer bathrooms;

    private Heating heatingType;
}
```

I have two more classes called Apartment and House which extend this property class

```
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Builder
@Getter
@Setter
@Data
public class Apartment extends Property {

    private Long houseId;

    private Integer floor;

}
```

I got the error  error: no suitable constructor found for Property(no arguments)
@Builder error: no suitable constructor found for Property(no arguments)

I do understand that you cannot instantiate abstract classes, I provided a constructor to the abstract class so the child classes can use it as super() and I got the following error
error: no suitable constructor found for Property(no arguments)
@Builder
^
constructor Property.Property(String,String,String,Float,Integer,Year,Integer,Heating,EnergySource,FlooringType,List,List,double,double) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
constructor Property.Property(PropertyBuilder) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in lengt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to annotate `Apartment` with [`@SuperBuilder`](https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/SuperBuilder) as well, **not** with [`@Builder`](https://projectlombok.org/features/Builder).

> The @SuperBuilder annotation produces complex builder APIs for your classes. In contrast to @Builder, @SuperBuilder also works with fields from superclasses. However, it only works for types. Most importantly, it requires that all superclasses also have the @SuperBuilder annotation.

Also, there is no need to explicitly add `@Getter` and `@Setter` when you are using [`@Data`](https://projectlombok.org/features/Data).

> @Data is a convenient shortcut annotation that bundles the features of @ToString, @EqualsAndHashCode, @Getter / @Setter and @RequiredArgsConstructor together